# Can we use Nuxt3 plugin in pinia store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt3

I want to use Nuxt3 plugin in Pinia Store. Currently If i use plugin in pinia store it will throw an error

**Here's the error image.**

[image]

**Here's the Code**

```js
// plugins/hello.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      hello: (msg) => `Hello ${msg}!`,
    },
  };
});
```

```js
// store/mainStore.ts

import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useMainStore = defineStore("MainStore", {
  state: () => ({
    errors: [],
  }),

  actions: {
    async logout() {
      const { $hello } = useNuxtApp();
      const msg = $hello("world");
      console.log(msg);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Composables aren't supposed to be used in random places, there's no way how provided value could be resolved this way. Not sure what would be the best place to do this in nuxt but generally you need to set $hello in store state early during app init, probably in root component. Same for router, etc

Comment: Using nuxt 3 plugin will work on pinia. I tested your code and it works on my end.

Comment: The above method works for me. Something to consider: Check _when_ do you actually call that function (`logout()`)? Does it occur on user click, or automatically early in lifecycle?